# Specific test behaviour for ruby gem -- mocking sleep

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

So I made a ruby gem that makes use of the `sleep` function. Using the gem in my applications causes the sleep function to be called in my tests.

What is the preferred approach to dealing with this? Right now, I'm mocking out sleep in the application but is there a way to disable sleeping for the test environment in the actual gem code? I don't think I can use `RACK_ENV` since the gem is not specific to a web app.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say it is difficult to know whether you are actually in a test-like environment, so the solution is not to try: provide a method that allows users of your gem to indicate that sleeps should not occur.

You could try and autodetect whether you should default to not sleeping (eg if it looks like rails is loaded and `Rails.env.test?` is true) while still allowing users of your gem to explicitly activate no sleep mode for the cases you can't autodetect.

Answer (score 0):

You can stub `sleep` like any other method:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:sleep)
```

Replace `Object` with the name of your class under test.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. That's what I am currently doing in my client application. I just thought there would be a way to package my gem with this functionality included so any consumers don't have to worry about doing this